# TensorFlow lite: High loss in accuracy after converting model to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have been trying TFLite to increase detection speed on Android but strangely my .tflite model now almost only detects 1 category.

I have done testing on the .pb model that I got after retraining a mobilenet and the results are good but for some reason, when I convert it to .tflite the detection is way off...

For the retraining I used the retrain.py file from [Tensorflow for poets 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

I am using the following commands to retrain, optimize for inference and convert the model to tflite:

```
python retrain.py \
--image_dir ~/tf_files/tw/ \
--tfhub_module https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v1_100_224/feature_vector/1 \
--output_graph ~/new_training_dir/retrainedGraph.pb \
-–saved_model_dir ~/new_training_dir/model/ \
--how_many_training_steps 500 

sudo toco \
--input_file=retrainedGraph.pb \
--output_file=optimized_retrainedGraph.pb \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--input_shape=1,224,224,3 \
--input_array=Placeholder \
--output_array=final_result \

sudo toco \
--input_file=optimized_retrainedGraph.pb \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--output_file=retrainedGraph.tflite \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--inference_input_type=FLOAT \
--input_arrays=Placeholder \
--output_array=final_result \
--input_shapes=1,224,224,3
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Where could the loss in accuracy come from?

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue while I was trying to convert a .pb model into .lite.

In fact, my accuracy would come down from 95 to 30!

Turns out the mistake I was committing was not during the conversion of .pb to .lite or in the command involved to do so. But it was actually while loading the image and pre-processing it before it is passed into the lite model and inferred using

```
interpreter.invoke()
```

command.

The below code you see is what I meant by pre-processing:

```
test_image=cv2.imread(file_name)
test_image=cv2.resize(test_image,(299,299),cv2.INTER_AREA)
test_image = np.expand_dims((test_image)/255, axis=0).astype(np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_tensor_index, test_image)
interpreter.invoke()
digit = np.argmax(output()[0])
#print(digit)
prediction=result[digit]
```

As you can see there are two crucial commands/pre-processing done on the image once it is read using "imread()":

i) The image should be resized to the size that is the "input_height" and "input_width" values of the input image/tensor that was used during the training. In my case (inception-v3) this was 299 for both "input_height" and "input_width". (*Read the documentation of the model for this value or look for this variable in the file that you used to train or retrain the model*)

ii) The next command in the above code is:

```
test_image = np.expand_dims((test_image)/255, axis=0).astype(np.float32)
```

I got this from the "formulae"/model code:

```
test_image = np.expand_dims((test_image-input_mean)/input_std, axis=0).astype(np.float32)
```

Reading the documentation revealed that for my architecture input_mean = 0 and input_std = 255.

When I did the said changes to my code, I got the accuracy that was expected (90%).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue on GitHub https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues and add the link here. 
Also please add more details on what you are retraining the last layer for.