# Tensorflow lite accuracy drop on mobile device

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I followed the both Tensorflow for Poets Tutorials:
[Tensorflow for Poets 1](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html) and [Tensorflow for Poets 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/index.html).
My retrained model gives accurate results for a test on my laptop but after converting into the .tflite file and trying to classify the same image on my Android device the accuracy drops under 1%.

I used the following commands to retrain und convert:

```
  python retrain.py \
  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
  --how_many_training_steps=500 \
  --model_dir=tf_files/models/ \
  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
  --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos

toco \
  --input_file=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.lite \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_shape=1,224,224,3 \
  --input_array=Placeholder \
  --output_array=final_result \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --input_data_type=FLOAT
```

Strangely the optimized file is almost as high as the original (both around 80 MB).

Using Tensorflow 1.9.0 and Python 3.6.6.

Any help or tip is appreciated!

Comment: It is answered here, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58583602/11517841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. Apparently the `ARCHITECTURE` variable was not set to the right value. So if anyone encounters the same problem, first of all check that