# accuracy loss when running inference on edge tpu with keras neural network 

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tpu, google-coral

I'm a student at the University of Bologna ( Italy) and I'm using the  Google Coral USB accelerator for my thesis.
I realized a keras neural network that classifies my data in four classes and the accuracy I get  is roughly 97%.
I performed a full integer post- training quantization since keras networks don't support quantization-aware training. I followed the guide on TensorFlow site but I had problems running inference on the edge tpu .
In particular my network undergoes an accuracy loss when the model is converted to a `tensorflowlite` one ( the accuracy drops to roughly the 25%) . This is due to quantization since the `tensorflowlite` model without quantization that runs on my pc is not affected by the conversion.
I  tried to scale my input data in a range [0, 255] with `MinMaxScaler`  but in this case , even if the accuracy of the `tensorflowlite` quantized model matches the one of the not converted one , the results are not satisfactory since the accuracy of the network itself is low.
I wonder if you could help me solve this problem.  Perhaps the values on my dataset are too low and the quantization fails to convert `float32` into `uint8` without information loss.
Below you'll find my python code.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import loadtxt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,MinMaxScaler,Normalizer
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import os
import time
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
import collections
import operator

"""Functions to work with classification models."""




Class = collections.namedtuple('Class', ['id', 'score'])




def input_tensor(interpreter):
  """Returns input tensor view as numpy array of shape (height, width, 3)."""
  tensor_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index']
  return interpreter.tensor(tensor_index)()[0]

def output_tensor(interpreter):
  """Returns dequantized output tensor."""
  output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()[0] 
  output_data = np.squeeze(interpreter.tensor(output_details['index'])()) #Remove single-dimensional entries from the shape of an array.
  scale, zero_point = output_details['quantization']
  return scale * (output_data - zero_point)


def set_input(interpreter, data):
  """Copies data to input tensor."""
  input_tensor(interpreter)[:] = data
  return data   


def get_output(interpreter, top_k=1, score_threshold=0.0):
  """Returns no more than top_k classes with score >= score_threshold."""
  scores = output_tensor(interpreter)
  classes = [
      Class(i, scores[i])
      for i in np.argpartition(scores, -top_k)[-top_k:]
      if scores[i] >= score_threshold
  ]
  return sorted(classes, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

#load the dataset


Modelli_Prova01_Nom01_Acc1L = loadtxt(r'/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/Modelli_Prova01_Nom01_Acc1L.csv',delimiter=',')
Modelli_Prova02_Nom01_Acc1L = loadtxt(r'/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/Modelli_Prova02_Nom01_Acc1L.csv',delimiter=',')
Modelli_Prova03_Nom01_Acc1L = loadtxt(r'/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/Modelli_Prova03_Nom01_Acc1L.csv',delimiter=',')
Modelli_Prova04_Nom01_Acc1L = loadtxt(r'/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/Modelli_Prova04_Nom01_Acc1L.csv',delimiter=',')
Modelli_Prova05_Nom01_Acc1L = loadtxt(r'/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/Modelli_Prova05_Nom01_Acc1L.csv',delimiter=',')

time_start = time.perf_counter()



#split x and y data (train and test)

Acc1L01_train,Acc1L01_test = train_test_split(Modelli_Prova01_Nom01_Acc1L ,test_size=0.015,random_state=42)
Acc1L02_train,Acc1L02_test = train_test_split(Modelli_Prova02_Nom01_Acc1L,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
Acc1L03_train,Acc1L03_test = train_test_split(Modelli_Prova03_Nom01_Acc1L,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
Acc1L04_train,Acc1L04_test = train_test_split(Modelli_Prova04_Nom01_Acc1L,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
Acc1L05_train,Acc1L05_test = train_test_split(Modelli_Prova05_Nom01_Acc1L,test_size=0.15,random_state=42)
Y1_train= np.zeros([len(Acc1L01_train)+len(Acc1L05_train),1]) 
Y2_train= np.ones([len(Acc1L02_train),1]) 
Y3_train= np.ones([len(Acc1L03_train),1]) +1
Y4_train= np.ones([len(Acc1L04_train),1]) +2
Y1_test= np.zeros([len(Acc1L01_test)+len(Acc1L05_test),1]) 
Y2_test= np.ones([len(Acc1L02_test),1])  
Y3_test= np.ones([len(Acc1L03_test),1]) +1
Y4_test= np.ones([len(Acc1L04_test),1]) +2

xAcc1L_train = np.concatenate((Acc1L01_train,Acc1L05_train,Acc1L02_train,Acc1L03_train,Acc1L04_train),axis=0)
xAcc1L_train=MinMaxScaler([0,255]).fit_transform(xAcc1L_train)
#xAcc1L_train=StandardScaler().fit_transform(xAcc1L_train)
#xAcc1L_train=Normalizer().fit_transform(xAcc1L_train)
#xAcc1L_train=np.transpose(xAcc1L_train)
yAcc1L_train = np.concatenate((Y1_train,Y2_train,Y3_train,Y4_train),axis=0)
xAcc1L_test = np.concatenate((Acc1L01_test,Acc1L05_test,Acc1L02_test,Acc1L03_test,Acc1L04_test),axis=0)
xAcc1L_test=Normalizer().fit_transform(xAcc1L_test)
#xAcc1L_test=MinMaxScaler([0,255]).fit_transform(xAcc1L_test)
#xAcc1L_test=StandardScaler().fit_transform(xAcc1L_test)
#xAcc1L_test=np.transpose(xAcc1L_test)
yAcc1L_test = np.concatenate((Y1_test,Y2_test,Y3_test,Y4_test),axis=0)
#1 hot encode y
one_hot_labelsAcc1L =to_categorical(yAcc1L_train, num_classes=4)
one_hot_labelsAcc1L_test = to_categorical(yAcc1L_test, num_classes=4)
#fit the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu', input_dim=30))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
es1 = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=100)
es2 = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, patience=100)

history=model.fit(xAcc1L_train, one_hot_labelsAcc1L,validation_data=(xAcc1L_test,one_hot_labelsAcc1L_test),epochs=500, batch_size=30, verbose=1, callbacks=[es1,es2])
#history=model.fit(tf.cast(xAcc1L_train, tf.float32), one_hot_labelsAcc1L,validation_data=(tf.cast(xAcc1L_test, tf.float32),one_hot_labelsAcc1L_test),epochs=500, batch_size=30, verbose=1, callbacks=[es1,es2])
time_elapsed = (time.perf_counter() - time_start)
print ("%5.1f secs " % (time_elapsed))

start=time.monotonic()
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(xAcc1L_test, one_hot_labelsAcc1L_test, batch_size=30, verbose=1)
#_, accuracy = model.evaluate(tf.cast(xAcc1L_test, tf.float32), one_hot_labelsAcc1L_test, batch_size=30, verbose=1)
print(accuracy)
inference_time = time.monotonic() - start
print('%.1fms ' % (inference_time * 1000))

# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()  
#predicted labels
predictions = model.predict(xAcc1L_test)
y_pred = (predictions > 0.5)
matrix = confusion_matrix(one_hot_labelsAcc1L_test.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1))
print('confusion matrix = \n',matrix)
print("Accuracy:",accuracy_score(one_hot_labelsAcc1L_test.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1)))



mod01=model.save('/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/rete_Nom01.h5')

#convert the model


#representative dataset       
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (tf.cast(xAcc1L_train, tf.float32))).batch(1)
print(train_ds)

def representative_dataset_gen():
    for input_value in train_ds: 
        yield [input_value]

print(model.layers[0].input_shape)

#integer post-training quantization

converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/rete_Nom01.h5') #all operations mapped on edge tpu
#converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
print(converter.representative_dataset)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
open('/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/rete_Nom01_quant.tflite', "wb").write(tflite_quant_model)



#compiler compila il modello quantizzato tflite per edge tpu
os.system("edgetpu_compiler \'/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/rete_Nom01_quant.tflite'")


#interpret the model

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter('/home/utente/Scrivania/csvtesi/rete_Nom01_quant_edgetpu.tflite',experimental_delegates=[tflite.load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1')])


interpreter.allocate_tensors()
idt=print(interpreter.get_input_details())
odt=print(interpreter.get_output_details())



for j in range(5):
  start = time.monotonic()
  o_test=np.arange(len(xAcc1L_test[:,0]))
  o_test=o_test[:,np.newaxis]
  for i in range (len(xAcc1L_test[:,0])):
    input=set_input(interpreter, xAcc1L_test[i,:])
    #print("inference input    %s" % input)
    interpreter.invoke()
    classes = get_output(interpreter,4)
    output = interpreter.get_tensor(interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['index'])#/255 con edgetpu
    #print("inference output    %s" % output)
    #print("inference classes      %s" % classes)
    a=np.array([one_hot_labelsAcc1L_test[i,:].argmax(axis=0)])
    b=np.array(output.argmax(axis=1))
    o_test[i]=b
    #if a==b:
      #print('good classification')
    #else: 
      #print('bad classification')
  inference_time = time.monotonic() - start
  print('%.1fms ' % (inference_time * 1000))
  #print(o_test)
  print("Accuracy:",accuracy_score(yAcc1L_test,o_test))
```

My input train dataset is part of  csv files and it's a matrix of dimensions = (1756,30) and my input test one is a matrix of (183,30).
This is how the data looks like (first two rows):

```
 [[-0.283589    -0.0831421  -0.199936   -0.144523   -0.215593   -0.199029   0.0300179   -0.0299262  -0.0759612  -0.0349733  0.102882    -0.00470235 -0.14267    -0.116636   -0.0842867  -0.124638   -0.107917   -0.0995006  -0.222817   -0.256093   -0.121859   -0.130829   -0.186091   -0.174511   -0.0715493  -0.0595195  -0.054914   -0.0362971  -0.0286576  -0.0409128],
[-0.226151  -0.0386177  -0.16834    -0.0768908  -0.166611   -0.161028   0.0493133   -0.00515959 -0.0362308  -0.00723895 0.105943    -0.010825   -0.142335   -0.10863    -0.0634201  -0.112928   -0.0927994  -0.0556194  -0.180721   -0.218341   -0.0934449  -0.100047   -0.134569   -0.119806   -0.0265749  -0.044841   -0.0538225  -0.017408   -0.00528171 -0.0248457]]
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938992/tensorflow-lite-high-loss-in-accuracy-after-converting-model-to-tflite). I would recommend opening up a github issue on this. There are numerous reasons why this could happen which could take days for one of us to diagnose (including how you set up the system, dependencies, etc.). They may be able to determine the issue a lot faster than us.

Comment: Yes, I've already deduced that it is a quantization problem. As I said , the accuracy loss is visible only with the TF lite model running post-training quantization ( the TF Lite one normally converted without quantization doesn't have this problem, accuracy is the same). The printed  input data of the interpreter are the correct ones in `float32` while the output data are obviously misinterpreted ( all predicted in the first class). So the quantised data are the problem and I don't know how to solve it. This is why I started the issue.

Comment: Can you also link to the tensorflow issue you have opened here if you opened one? I believe you have also contacted us (the Coral Team), however, this is more suited for the tensorflow team. A note, this isn't very well documented, but to my experience, adding some calibration steps (maybe loop 100 times) in representative_data_gen will help.